# Figure as pdf page

Tags: floats

Hi I have a file with two pages of text and several figures - pdf. I am not able to reach the order I want.

```
\newpage
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{2.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

I used `[h]` and `\newpage` but the text is at the beginning of the file and the figures follow although the document start with a figure and then is newpage. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is rather hard to understand your question with no example, but `[h]`  usually generates a warning that it is being changed to `[ht]` but even then it is quite likely to force the figure to the end of the document as it prevents the figure being placed on a page on its own (as it removes `p`)  but if you have no caption why use figure at all, why not simply use `\includegraphics` ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Using only includegraphics works.